# Relative url in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm sending an ajax request with relative url

```
 $.post("wp-content/themes/site/function.php", {

    }, function (data) {});
```

It's working fine if my url is http://yourdomain.com/page. But if the url is http://yourdomain.com/page/

then it's sending http://yourdomain.com/page/wp-content/themes/site/function.php. but I want http://yourdomain.com/site/wp-content/themes/function.php

Comment: what do u want? `http://yourdomain.com/site/wp-content/themes/function.php` -->  `/site/wp-content/themes/function.php` is completely different to `wp-content/themes/site/function.php`. Check your pathes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with a leading `/`:

```
$.post("/wp-content/themes/site/function.php", {}, function (data) {});
```